# VLC media player installation on RHEL 9

Tags: linux, audio, video, redhat-enterprise-linux, vlc-media-player

Please help me to install VLC media player on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9. I tried these [installation steps](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-redhat.html), but they failed.
I tried to skip few packages during the installation too, but I could not install VLC.

I tried:

```
$> su -
#> yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
#> yum install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-8.noarch.rpm
#> yum install vlc
#> yum install vlc-core (for minimal headless/server install)
#> yum install python-vlc (optionals)
```

Although the above steps were mentioned for RHEL 8, there are no instructions on the web for how to install VLC on RHEL 9.

Answer (score 1):

To install on this way will be much better to use command like:

```
yum localinstall ...
```

or

```
dnf localinstall ...
```

This way will follow and install dependent packages.

So the procedure will be:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-9-$(arch)-rpms
dnf localinstall https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm
```

and then

```
dnf install vlc
```

Comment: Both `install` and `localinstall` will resolve dependencies.  `localinstall` is actually deprecated because `install` will behave the same way if you provide it a file path or a URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the VLC instructions for RHEL 8 on your RHEL 9 system, you are mixing packages built for different major versions of the OS.  Definitely don't do that, because at best you will have uninstallable packages, and at worse you will break your system entirely.

For RHEL 9, you want to use EPEL 9 and RPM Fusion 9 repos.  The instructions will be the same as what is on the VLC website, just change the 8 to 9 in the URLs.

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm
yum install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-9.noarch.rpm
yum install vlc
```